# Adding multiple -and and -or statements in WHERE clause in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm currently using Powershell, and i'm trying to sort data in my variable that i'm pulling from another system. At the moment i'm trying to use one -and statement and -or statements after an -eq sign. So I was wondering what's the correct way I need to make the syntax in my where statement.

```
$DLPList | Select Node.NodeName, Properties.OSType, PropsView.version, Node.NodeTextPath2 | where PropsView.version -ne '1.4.706.172' -and (Properties.OSType -eq $win7 -or $win8 -or $win81 -or $win10)
```

I know there's multiple other stuff on this, but everything i've tried so far doesn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: does your `Select-Object` section work? i have never seen `Property.SubProp` used before. for the `-or` stuff ... you CANNOT combine them like that. you could likely use `$Thing -in @($OneThing, $TwoThing, $ThreeThing)`.

Comment: FWIW, it seems @trevor-lines answered his question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634283/182742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, what I figured out for this is that you cannot just add use -or. Instead you must do Properties.ostype for each one. Here is the code that I came up with to get it to work. Also a little tip is to do Where-Object before Select-Object to save computing power.

```
$DLPList = $list1 | Where-Object{ $_.'UDLP.prodversion' -lt '9.5.704.112' -and ($_.'Properties.OSType' -ne 'Windows XP') -and ($_.'EPOComputerProperties.OSType' -ne 'Windows Vista') -and ($_.'EPOComputerProperties.OSType' -ne 'Windows 2003') -and ($_.'Properties.OSType' -ne 'Windows 2003 R2') -and ($_.'EPOComputerProperties.OSType' -ne 'Windows 2008') -and ($_.'Properties.OSType' -ne 'Windows 2008 R2') -and ($_.'Properties.OSType' -ne 'Windows Server 2012' -and ($_.'Properties.OSType' -ne 'Windows Server 2012 R2') -and ($_.'Properties.OSType' -ne 'Windows Server 2016')) } | Select-Object Node.NodeName, Properties.OSType, UDLP.productversion, Node.NodeText | Sort-Object -Property Node.NodeText -Descending
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use the script block version of where-object.  Also note that -and and -or have EQUAL PRECEDENCE in powershell, which is very unusual in a language.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding brackets and replacing the chained boolean operators with a regular expression "-match" operator condition:

```
$DLPList | Select Node.NodeName, Properties.OSType, PropsView.version, Node.NodeTextPath2 | where { $_.'PropsView.version' -ne '1.4.706.172' -and ($_.'Properties.OSType' -match "($win7|$win8|$win81|$win10)") }
```

Here's sample code that works for me:

```
$DLPList = @(2, 4, 6, 7)
$DLPList | where { ($_ -ne 7) -and ($_ -lt 10) -and ($_ -gt 0) }
2
4
6

$DLPList | where { ($_ -ne 7) -and ($_ -match "(4|5|11)" -and ($_ -gt 0)) }
4
```

Comment: that 2nd line is _wrong_. [*sigh ...*] it will give you `2,4,6` ... and both `2` & `6` aint  correct results. the reason is that the 2nd part does `$_ -eq 4` and then compares the _boolean_ from that with `-or 5`. ///// you are NOT doing what you seem to think you are doing. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Of course, you are right; thank you. I've updated the answer to use the regular expression "-match" operator.

Comment: kool! glad to see it fixed & working ... [*grin*] that is a classic error with chaining logical operators - i've done it more than once!

Comment: Wouldn't that be  $_.PropsView.version and $_.Properties.OSType?