# Adding multiple clauses in Where-Object statement

Tags: powershell

I know others have posted about this, but every thing i've tried so far hasn't worked. The issue i'm running into is that when I add brackets around my Where-Object statement, it turns the column that i'm trying to filter on into a function. Thus not allowing it to run.

```
$AgentList | Select-Object Leaf.NodeName, Properties.OSType, PropsView.version, BranchNode.Node | Where-Object{ (PropsView.version -lt '5.5.0.447') -and (Properties.OSType -ne 'Mac OS X')} | Sort-Object -Property EPOBranchNode.NodeTextPath2 -Descending
```

I'm hoping to be able to filter on both PropsView.version and Properties.OSType at the same time. At the moment I can do one or the other, but right when I try to add both I run into the error.

```
The term 'PropsView.version' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: You need to prefix the properties in the filter with`$_.`.  Like this: `($_.PropsView.version -lt '5.5.0.447') -and ($_.Properties.OSType -ne 'Mac OS X') `.  Also, consider swapping your `Select-Object` and `Where-Object` calls as you are creating objects that you then through away (if they don't match the filter).

Comment: Try `$_.'PropsView.version'`. It will also help if you show the output of `$AgentList | Format-List | Select -First 1`

Comment: @boxdog I attempted that earlier, and the issue i'm running into is that it no longer actually sorts the data and instead just pulls everything. Do I need to prefix the properties in the Select-Object clause as well? And thanks for the advice.

Comment: I figured it out, I was just making a simple mistake of not adding the single quotes after $_.. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
$AgentList | Select-Object Leaf.NodeName, Properties.OSType, PropsView.version, BranchNode.Node | Where-Object{ ($_.'PropsView.version' -lt '5.5.0.447') -and ($_.'Properties.OSType' -ne 'Mac OS X')} | Sort-Object -Property EPOBranchNode.NodeTextPath2 -Descending
```

Just needed to add the $_. and then single quotes around the column i'm sorting. It was the single quotes that I wasn't adding that messed me up. Thanks for the help everyone!